# Jira REST API returns Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an issue in jira using the following code. I had run this code and it was working fine earlier. But now, It returns bad request,Please help.
Thanks.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var data = new Issue();
            data.fields.project.key = "CAM";
            data.fields.summary = "test";
            data.fields.description = "test";
            data.fields.issuetype.name = "Task";

            string postUrl = "https://abcd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/latest";

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(postUrl);
            byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username@gmail.com:password");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

            //System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<string>(data, jsonFormatter);
            System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = new System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<Issue>(data, jsonFormatter);
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("issue", content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.Write(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: which rest api version are you using? different versions have different urls, I hope you have verified you are posting to correct api url!

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya Yes it's for api/2 only. I verified.

Comment: Before going deep can you please try adding '/' at the end of your base url i.e. string postUrl = "https://abcd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/latest/", as it might be possible not to generate correct url. Though it should return 404 in that case.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya  It's done using - "https://cmsc17.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/"

Comment: Great!! So ultimately url was the issue, right?

Comment: Yes! And I changed my code, too. @MukeshModhvadiya

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link :
`string postUrl = "https://abcd.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/";`